# Execute a CallableStatement blocks the application

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, hibernate-entitymanager

I have a backend server writed on Java 6, with a JBoss 5.1. I have to call a Oracle procedure (stored on a package) on that code into a method like:

```
cs = conn.prepareCall("{call <user>.<package>.<procedure_name>(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");

        cs.setString(1, <data>);
        cs.setString(2, <data>);
        cs.setString(3, <data>);
        cs.setDate(4, <data>);
        cs.setString(5, <data>);

        cs.registerOutParameter(6, Types.VARCHAR);
        cs.registerOutParameter(7, Types.VARCHAR);
        cs.registerOutParameter(8, Types.BIGINT);

        cs.setInt(9, <data>);


        try{
            cs.execute();
        }catch (RuntimeException e){
            e.getMessage();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.getMessage();
        }


        Long numerr   = cs.getLong(8);
```

The problem appears when I call `cs.execute()`. That call blocks the execution and can't continue normal execution and persist data.

It's necessary to say that this procedure normal execution **insert** data into another tables based on a third table in which I insert previously the data with a normal class creation and an `EntityManager.persist(<entity>)` and `EntityManager.flush()`.

It's not a **Grant permissions** problem, because I can execute the procedure on **SQLDeveloper** with proper sentence and the proper User/password.

Comment: Have the inserts done by calling the procedure in SQL Developer been committed or rolled back? Sounds like the insert is just blocked by another session.

Comment: Mmmm, I don't think so, although I tried to insert my previous data, close connection, create another connection, create callable statement and then execute and the problem still persists, `cs.execute()` still blocks

Comment: But you said you ran it successfully from SQL Developer. I'm talking about that session, not something you did earlier from Java.

Comment: No, thats not the problem. Even when I close SQL Developer, even restarting the computer. The problem still persists.

Comment: Could be Java persist blocking the call procedure statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I discovered what was the problem. You can't use at the same time the EntityManager an persist an entity and later execute a procedure which you have to call natively. So the solution was to persist my entity natively (by an insert, using `PreparedStatemnt`);

```
"Insert into <table> (<column1>, <column2>,...,<columnN>) values (?, ?,...,?)"
```

And later execute the procedure in the right way:

```
"{call <user>.<package>.<procedure_name>(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}"
```

The reason seems to be that you can't execute into the same `@Transactional` method two different ways of execution: EntityManager persist-way and native procedure execution-way.

I hope this could help anyone :-)